# What can I do to prevent possible gradual erosion on this small slope

Tags: landscaping, walkway

Just had a paver walk installed and the end of it has an elevation of 6" from the grass edge 18" away.

I live in Maryland.  I was thinking about the possibility of gradual erosion due to rain coming off the edge of the paver walkway.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: There's very little context in that photo. The critical bit that's missing is the amount of water that's expected to flow over that area. A photo of the entire drainage basin would be appropriate, as well as some in formation about your climate. However, "should I be concerned" simply doesn't fit our Q&A format to begin with. Please revise to ask something that can be answered more objectively.

Comment: I agree with isherwood I am always concerned about erosion but would it be a problem here we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If the pavers were installed properly--and it looks like they were--the edge banding should be staked into the ground much deeper than 6". So, structurally, I think there is nothing to worry about.

Now, *aesthetically*, it does seem a little wonky. But we can't see the larger picture here.

That said, if you are worried about a bit of erosion over time, I'd suggest removing the mulch up to the pavers and plant grass there. The grass will help stop any erosion over that small of a slope.